# "Aw Snap" mesasge in Chrome when using Silverlight

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight-5.0

I'm getting the "Aw Snap" message consistently in Chrome when performing the following:

1. Load a page that displays a silverlight rendering
2. Click on a button that fires off a fancybox containing an iFrame that contains the same Silverlight rendering
3. Close the fancybox
4. Receive the dreaded "Aw Snap" message
5. Reload page and page loads up again

Notes:

- This does not happen in IE
- This does not happen in Firefox
- When I go to **chrome://crashes/** there is no record of the crash

---

Chrome Version: 24.0.1312.57

Silverlight Version: Silverlight 5 (5.1.10411.0)

---

Searching through Google's Chrome issue board yielded very little and any issue reported that was similar was either years old or did not have a response. Hoping that someone has encountered the same problem and has a workaround.